# Proof that If G = (V , E ) is a graph, then S is an independent set ⇐⇒ V − S is a vertex cover.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have the following :
  [Proof](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2009/cmsc451/npc2.pdf):

Proof.  ⇒ Suppose $S$ is an independent set, and let $ e = (u, v )$
be some edge. Only one of $u, v$ can be in S . Hence, at least one of
$u, v$ is in $V − S$ . So, $V − S$ is a vertex cover.

⇐ Suppose $V − S$ is a vertex cover, and let $u, v ∈ S$ . There
can’t be an edge between $u$ and $v$ (otherwise, that edge wouldn’t
be covered in $V − S$ ). So, S is an independent set. #

But when I construct a Graph as shown bellow:

[image]

I supposed the blue nodes to be the Independent Set IS. and after that I picked up an edge $e1= (5,6)$. but I see it does not satisfy the first condition of the proof "...and let $ e = (u, v )$
be some edge. Only one of $u, v$ can be in S ", Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, but perhaps the wording is a bit vague/imprecise. A better way to say it is:

> At most one of $u,v$ can be in $S$.

Then when we negate both sides, we see where the "at least one" part came from.

Comment: ok,correct thank you, can you rank me to rank your answer, becaue my reputation 11 <15

Answer (score 2):

In your example the blue vertices are an independent set and the remaining ones are vertex cover. Note that a vertex cover can contain an edge, so containing the edge 5-6 is no problem.

Comment: yes that is true